# Generate float by iterating

Tags: ruby

I want to generate `1.1`, `2.2`, `3.3`, ... but the only way I can come up with is:

```
100.times do |i|
  ary << "#{i}.#{i}".to_f
end
```

Is there a more elegant or efficient way to do this?

Comment: What do you want in your series after 9.9? Your code will generate 10.10, 11.11, etc.

Comment: Not without precision errors if you restrict yourself to floats, since just about any other solution will involve floating-point arithmetic. Though I will say `(1..100).map { |i| "#{i}.#{i}".to_f }` is probably more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a different way to do things, but I think what you have works just fine.